# What does "width" mean in Hive Query Plan?

Tags: hive, explain

```
TableScan [TS_0] (rows=1217 width=292)
```

Rows is how many rows are in the table (1217 in this case). But what does "width" mean ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, but not at 100% that `width` means data size in bytes

Comment: Width - Number of bytes per row. also not 100% sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this [Statistics](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/plan/Statistics.java) class, The width is the datasize/numrows, so it is essentially the means data size in bytes

Comment: I've checked against the table data and it is indeed so. If you divide the `rawDataSize` by `numRows` you get the `width` value.